# Updating older Xcode project but now navigationBar background is extending below height of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app originally built for iOS 11 which I am updating for iOS 15, however I have an issue with the top navigationbar in one of my views.

It's a little hard to explain but basically it seems like the top navigation bar has extra height and extends below the bottom of the navigationbar itself, the navigation bar is just the standard height of 44pts which I've checked by printing it to console using `print(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.intrinsicContentSize.height.description as Any)`.

As part of my attempts to figure out what's going on I have set both the Standard and Scroll Edge appearance Background colour settings on the navigationbar in the Main storyboard to yellow / orange, the navigationbar itself is set to black, so this shows the extra navigationbar area which extends below the bar itself.

I've uploaded a gif capturing scrolling up and down in the view, you can see the extended height area showing in yellow or orange and the content of the view scrolling up behind the navigationbar.

[image: GIF capture of the app scrolling up and down]

I do appreciate that it's tricky to debug without a lot more specifics about other aspects of how the app works etc but I was hoping that it may have been something that other people have encountered and may have a hunch about the cause, does anyone have any initial thoughts on what could be going on here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you doing anything in particular to position the nav bar?  Have you set constraints on it or anything?

Comment: @ScottThompson I do have constraints set on it but it's basically in the standard position in the layout in the storyboard and has the standard constraints. I've tried resetting constraints of the other elements in that layout but that didn't affect the navigation bar.